# Should I link my Social Security Number to my bank account?

Tags: united-states, checking-account, bank-of-america

I opened a checking account at Bank of America in California (a [Bank of America Core Checking Account](https://www.bankofamerica.com/deposits/checking/personal-checking-account.go) to be precise).

I have the option to link my Social Security Number to my bank account: what are the pros/cons of doing so?

If that matters, I am a non-resident alien, F1 student living in the USA.

Comment: What do you mean "link"? You have to provide tax id to the bank, which is your SSN

Comment: @littleadv Only my passport was required to open the bank account. By link I mean indicating my SSN somewhere in my bank account.

Comment: As I recall, if you don't provide a SSN, the bank is required to withhold 20% of all interest payments and send the money to the IRS as income tax withheld. I presume there will be some issues with reconciling your 1099-INT statement and your income tax return. On the other hand, if you are an impecunious student whose bank balance rarely exceeds a few thousand dollars, the pennies in interest that you will earn from the back might not even generate a Form 1099-INT from your bank: the amount will  be small enough that the bank does not need to report it to the IRS at all.

Comment: @DilipSarwate when I just moved to this country the bank refused to pay me any interest or give me any credit without SSN

Comment: @DilipSarwate My impression is that it's 30%, not 20%, that they take if you don't give them a SSN.

Comment: @littleadv Which bank and when was it? Today at Bank of America no SSN was asked, only passport. The bank employee told me that SSN was optional (and refused to tell me the pros/cons).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt they opened the account for me alright, they just wouldn't pay interest on it (although it was otherwise interest-bearing account). That was Wells Fargo many many years ago.

Comment: (@LorenPechtel) Backup withholding is 28% [per here](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/backup-withholding-b-processes) or if they reorg the website again publication 1281 is and I'm sure will remain archived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, two reasons for linking my Social Security Number to my bank account:

1. Avoiding issues with the IRS
2. Building credit history